# Why do some c++ compilers let you take the address of a literal?

Tags: c++, rvalue

A C++ compiler that I will not name lets you take the address of a literal, int *p = &42;

Clearly 42 is an r-value and most compilers refuse to do so.

Why would a compiler allow this? What could you do with this other than shoot yourself in the foot?

Comment: Why won't you name the compiler?

Comment: @JaredPar Perhaps because he invented it. :) :)

Comment: @JaredPar: I realize this is a bit after the fact (5 years) but VS2013 is letting me do this for a class's i.e. `Foo *p = &Foo()` but not with literal integers. It stops working when I turn it up to warning level 4 and treat warnings as errors. After which this works for integers and classes, I think it may be valid C++: `const int *p = &(const int&)42;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What if you needed a pointer to an integer with the value of 42? :)

C++ references are much like automatically dereferenced pointers. One can create a constant reference to a literal, like this:

```
const int &x = 42;
```

It effectively requires the compiler to initialize a pointer with the address of an integer with the value 42, as you might subsequently do this:

```
const int *y = &x;
```

Combine that with the fact that compilers need to have logic to distinguish between a value which has not had its address taken, and one which has, so it knows to store it in memory. The first need not have a memory location, as it can be entirely temporary and stored in a register, or it may be eliminated by optimization. Taking the address of the value potentially introduces an alias the compiler can't track and inhibits optimization. So, applying the **`&`** operator may force the value, whatever it is, into memory.

So, it's possible you found a bug that combined these two effects.

Answer (score 3):

Because 42 is the answer to life, the universe and everything. When asked for its address it is the answer itself.

Comment: Yep, I know that it's not helpful, but I couldn't help myself, it was a ... in german we call it "Steilvorlage" :)

Comment: +1 because presumably you have absorbed whatever lesson is to be learned from this and people are just piling on for no good reason.

Comment: @Newton Falls but now he had a net gain of points due to upvotes being worth 5 times as much as downvotes.

Comment: @rlbond There again proving that no good deed goes unpunished.  I didn't expect to start a trend.

Comment: I promise I won't do it again. But thanks for the votes anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

Tongue slightly (nut by no means totally) in cheek:

I'd say that in C++ application code taking the address of an integer whether lvalue or rvalue is almost always a mistake. Even using integers, for doing anything much more than controlling loops or counting is probably a design error, and if you need to pass an integer to a function which might change it, use a reference.

Answer (score 0):

Found something related to rvalue references in C++0x -- move semantics
http://www.artima.com/cppsource/rvalue.html

Answer (score 0):

> It effectively requires the compiler to initialize a pointer with the address of an integer with the value 42

Then why, in some compilers, we can't take the address of a literal **directly** ?

```
int* ptr = &10;
```

The reference:

```
int& ref = 10;
```

is almost the same thing as a pointer, though...