# What is the type of a builtin datatype in C and C++?

Tags: c++, c, types, built-in-types

When we write `int a;`, it doesn't mean that we are creating an object of class int.

1. What does it mean?
2. What is the type of the datatype int in C and C++?
3. Which header file shows what it is?

Comment: But `int a;` does indeed create an object in C++. It's an object of type `int` with indeterminate value if it has automatic storage duration; or with value `0`, if it has static storage duration.

Comment: You are mashing C and C++ together ¬_¬

Comment: Eh, no it doesn't. Check out the assembly output of a program that defines "int a;".

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Really? See the first comment here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8571796/what-is-the-scope-of-a-literal-value-and-how-does-the-compiler-allocate-memory

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes it is not creating an object, it is creating some plain old data which is not an object (i.e. which is not an instance of some class), even in C++.

Comment: `int` is not a class. its one of primitive types; unsigned integer type.

Comment: @AnishaKaul: That comment is wrong (as explained in the 7th comment there). In C++, an "object" is any region of storage.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Plain old data are objects, just as much as class types are objects.  The definition `int a;` creates an object of type `int`.

Comment: @AnishaKaul, refer to the standard 3.9-8, an object-type is basically any type excluding references and functions. The primitives are called "arithmetic types", but is a subset of object type.

Comment: Are we talking about C or C++ here? Big difference. Pick one and fix the tags.

Comment: @Cody: there's a big difference between C and C++, but as it happens the answer to this particular question is the same in both (different standards citations, but to the same result). Is it really necessary to ask two questions?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> When we write `int a;`, it doesn't mean that we are creating an object of class int.

`int a;` does indeed create an object in C++. It's an object of type `int` with indeterminate value if it has automatic storage duration; or with value `0`, if it has static storage duration. But there is no "class `int`" because `int` is not a class type.

`int` is a:

- integral type;
- signed type;
- arithmetic type;
- fundamental type;
- scalar type;
- standard layout type;
- trivially copyable type;
- POD type;
- trivial type;

Seems like you got a bit confused in your previous question :)

In `int x = 12;`, you are creating an object of type `int` that is named `x` and has value 12.

The idea of *object* in C++ is not the same as in most other languages, and most certainly is not the same as is commonly used in *object-oriented programming* circles. An object in C++ is a region of storage.

If something has a type, it's either an object, a reference, or a function.

> Which header file shows what it is?

The language simply requires that the type `int` has to exist and have certain characteristics (like being integral and having a sign). All compilers I know of simply treat all the builtin types specially and that's why you won't find a definition for them in the standard library headers. In fact, they can't provide a definition for them in any header using C++, because *the language doesn't provide any means of defining fundamental types*. They could only either:

- define it as a compound type (which would be wrong); or
- define it using compiler-specific extensions.

The builtin types are effectively magic.

Comment: I think some people might get confused with languages like Java where almost everything is and object and an `Object` (as in they are instance of the `Object` class, or derive from it), yet it still has some primitive types such as `int` or `flaot` etc.

Though I have to admit, I am not familiar with the notion of object you seem to be putting forth here.

Comment: @thecoshman: The notion of an object is formally defined in the C++-standard.

Comment: It's also a _standard layout type_, _trivially copyable type_, _POD type_, and _trivial type_  :)

Comment: Ok, but what is the actual `type` of `int` in C++/C?

Comment: @Anisha: `int` **is the type**.

Comment: My question was how is int defined in C++? As a struct/class/file/pipe what?

Comment: @Anisha: it's a builtin type. Compilers treat it specially without having a definition anywhere. It cannot be a class though.

Comment: Do you have a reference link which says your point? Some C++ standard or anything? Asking this since if someone asks me the same I can't say *because Martinho told me therefore it is true* :)

Comment: In the latest C++ standard this is described in sections §3.9.1 and §3.9.2. These make the distinction between fundamental and compound types (classes, arrays, etc). `int` is a fundamental type, and thus cannot be a class.

Comment: I checked that standard, couldn't find anything showing in what way is int defined. BTW if you don't write @Anisha i won't get the notifications.

Comment: @AnishaKaul: if you can't find it in the standard, either the standard is severely broken or you didn't read it too well... FWIW: http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1539.pdf

Comment: @sehe The standard which I have is `n3242`. I'll check out your standard.

Comment: @AnishaKaul: Sorry, meant to post n3242 of course. Don't know why I got the wrong link. Anyways It looks like I posted the C11 draft by accident :)

Answer (score 4):

The `int` type is built-in inside the language and the compiler. On most implementations, it is some kind of machine [word](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_%28computer_architecture%29) (fitting into the processor's registers), as efficiently handled by the processor. On my (Debian/Linux/AMD64) system, it is a 32 bits word, usually aligned to 4 bytes.

There is no header defining it. The compiler has an intimate knowledge about `int`. And it is not a class or some aggregate type, it is atomic in the sense of not being composed of smaller stuff.

All languages I know have predefined or built-in types (or names), which are specially known to the compiler. For example, in *Ocaml*, the [Pervasives](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Pervasives.html) module is built-in.

Comment: I added a link to explain *machine words*

Comment: "... On most implementations, it is some kind of machine word" - not true at all for all 64-bit Linux's, where `long` is the machine word.

Comment: The definition of `word` on x86-64 is depending of the context. But I did add "fitting into a register" and a 32 bits int fit into a 32 bits [sub-] register like EAX (not RAX) on AMD64

Answer (score 1):

(as far as C is concerned)

`int` is a primitive type, to the extend that it is a language keyword. No header of any sort declares it.

However, there are a lot of `typedef`s defined in headers which do use primitive types as "backends" and which do require that you include the relevant headers (i.e `uint32_t`, `uint16_t`, etc etc).

Answer (score 1):

When you type "int a;", you let the compiler know that any symbols "a" in a's scope have the datatype "int".

Answer (score -1):

`int` is a built-in type, no header file defines it.
What `int a;`  means depends on where this line of code is located.

It can be

- local variable
- object field
- global variable

Note that `int a;` is not a good way to define local variable. you should always initialize it, there are several ways to do so:

```
int a = 5; //value is 5
int a = int(); //default constructor, value is 0
```

Comment: 'int a();' does not default construct and int sadly.  You want 'int a=int();'  Lookup "most vexing parse"